# Using exported variable in MDX does not work

Tags: next.js, markdown, jsx, mdxjs

In the [Getting Started documentation of mdxjs.com](https://mdxjs.com/getting-started#hello-world) we see the following documentation:

```
Defining variables with exports
If you need to define a variable in your MDX document, you can use an export to do so. Not only do exports emit data, they instantiate data you can reference in JSX blocks:

export const myVariable = 'Yay!'

# Hello, world!

<div>{myVariable}</div>
```

However if we copy that code and paste it into the playground: https://mdxjs.com/playground, it fails with `ReferenceError: myVariable is not defined`.

I'm running into the same issue when I try to import an MDX document into my nextjs app.

This works:

```
Sentence with details about <Text product={product}/>
```

Where `<Text/>` is simply a dummy component:

```
const Text = ({ product }) => {
    return (
        <>{product}</>
    )
}
```

But I shouldn't have to do the above. I simply want my MDX to look like this:

```
Sentence with details about {product}
```

Am I missing something here?

Appreciate your help!